# Is there any graphic-accelerated PDF reader for Android?

Tags: pdf, ebook-reader, hardware-acceleration

I use Adobe's Reader and ThinkFree Office, but they both are too slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Adobe would typically be the one of the first ones to implement hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Android 3.0 (Honeycomb), Google introduced hardware accelerated 2D rendering pipeline. For now it's a tablet-only feature, but hopefully we'll get that in the unified Ice Cream Sandwich platform.

That should be a bit with that slowness issue with PDF readers since they are only able to do software rendering in Gingerbread and older.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hardware accelerated PDF reader for Android at the time I am writing this (correct/edit me if I am wrong).

As [kernal already sad,](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11345/is-there-any-graphic-accelerated-pdf-reader-for-android/11363#11363) the performance depends on your phone. You could try to downsize the images in the PDFs for better performance on your android device.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the better choice is [ezPDF Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=udk.android.reader&feature=search_result). It's a paid app, but the screenshots look just great!

Remember the performance depends on which phone do you have... :-/

Comment: Yeah, but is it hardware accelerated on phone that support it? E.g. GS II and Sensation?